# Mule not finding properties file using Spring

Tags: java, spring, mule, properties-file

I have a Mule flow that I wish to configure via a Spring .properties file. I have read the Mule documentation on how to do this and I'm pretty sure I have it correct, but I get:

```
Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
class path resource [agt-commission.properties] cannot be opened because 
it does not exist
```

My Mule flow XML file begins with:

```
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" 
xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" 
xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" 
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" 
xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file"
xmlns:jdbc-ee="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc" 
xmlns:data-mapper="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper" 
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation" 
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
version="EE-3.4.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/jdbc/current/mule-jdbc-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/data-mapper/current/mule-data-mapper.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking 
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<spring:beans>
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:agt-commission.properties"/>
</spring:beans>
```

My properties file is located in the `src/main/app` folder as specified by the documentation and I have copied and pasted the file name, so I know that is the same.

[image: Project structure]

I am running the project from Mule Studio (3.5.0) as a Mule application.

Why can't Spring find the properties file?

Comment: can you see your proerties file inside your classes folder?

Comment: Not sure how to do that. Where would the classes folder be?

Comment: @DebojitSaikia I've checked the `/bin/` folder where all the `.class` files are generated and the `.properties` file is not copied there. Not sure how to force it to be there though.

Comment: clean and build your project. if it doesn't go there even after that, try manually copying `.proerties` file there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your `agt-commission.properties` file in `src/main/resources` instead of `src/main/app`.

By default files under `app` doesn't get copied to `classes` which is causing `FileNotFoundException`

Answer (score 0):

For Property placeholder files the better location is src/main/resources.

As properties file to be provided in the app folder, is the mule-deploy properties which has the details of the application deployment.

Move your resource file to src/main/resources and it should work with your config file.

Note: This will work when the build in the POM has got the src/main/resources  declared as resource

```
 <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
 </resources>
```

Hope this helps.